# Could not connect to the Analysis service in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, database, service, analysis

I am trying to add Analysis Service in SQL Server 2017, but I get this error:

> No connection could be made  because  the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2383

[image]